# Maximal clique problem

Tags: graph-theory, decision-theory, social-choice-theory

I understood what clique is all the nodes of the sub graph have to be connected to each other. In the following figure, it says that the maximal clique is {1,2,3,4,5}. But as per the definition of clique {1,2,3,4,5} is not a clique. Could someone explain this?

```
                    1
                   *  *
                  *     *
                 2*******3
                 *       *
                 *       *
                 4       5
                  *     *
                   *    * 
                    *  *
                      6
```

Consider the ***** as an edge.

Comment: {1,2,3,4,5} is indeed not a clique. {1,2,3} is the largest clique in this graph.

Comment: It may be better to upload the original image or provide a citation to the original problem.  Perhaps the way your figure is drawn here does not exactly match the original figure in question.

Comment: By connected, do you mean *adjacent*?  Two vertices can be connected without being adjacent.  In the usual definition, a *clique* is a complete subgraph, i.e., any two vertices are adjacent.  Your version of cliques is known to most mathematicians as *connected subgraphs*.

Comment: I tried uploading it but I dont have reputation 10 so it didnt allow me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of clique is correct.
However the maximal clique in that graph is {1,2,3} and not {1,2,3,4,5}.
{1,2,3,4,5} is not even a clique in that graph.

Answer (score 0):

A clique of a graph is a subset of the vertices with the property that each vertex of this subset is adjacent to every other vertex of the subset (complete induced subgraph)